# Проверка сайта на редирект или на содержание в коде определенного текста

Tags: javascript, jquery, скрипт, проверка

Здравствуйте. Не разбираюсь в скриптах, но нужна помощь.
Допустим есть страница со списком моих сайтов.

- mysite1.ru
- mysite2.ru
- mysite3.ru и т.д.

Нужно по url проверять код на содержание в нем текста(допустим "othersite").
и если код содержится, то менять бекграунд под названием сайта на другой цвет. 
проверку производить во время загрузки страницы с сайтами.

Возможно ли такое организовать с помощью jquery допустим?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На php такая задача решается довольно легко

```
    $sites = ['http://mysite1.com', 'http://mysite2.com', 'http://mysite3.com/page.php'];
    $search = 'Слово или строка';
    $pattern = '/' . $search . '/';
    foreach ($sites as $item) {
        $site = file_get_contents($item);
        if (preg_match($pattern, $site))
            echo '<div style="background-color: green;">' . $item . '</div><hr>';
        else
            echo '<div style="background-color: red;">' . $item . '</div><hr>';
    }
```

но на javascript увы не получится такое сделать через политику безопасности

Comment: Спасибо огромное, чуток переделал под себя. работает как надо!